# Werewolves of Miller's Hollow Tie

Tags: werewolf

In a recent game of Miller's Hollow, the game ended when a werewolf killed a witch, and the witch killed the werewolf with their poison potion. In a situation such as this, which group wins?

The problem is, the rulebook says that

> The Townsfolk win if they manage to eliminate all Werewolves.
>
> The Werewolves win if they kill the last Townsperson.

The timing on death is only described as the following:

> The Moderator will reveal the results in the morning.

Seeing as the Witch can heal themselves,

> The Witch can use either potion on him/herself if he/she wishes.

That means that the answer isn't that the witch dies before they can act. Who wins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the game can end without any player alive. It happens sometimes. And in that case, the game is a tie.

With the basic rules, there can be as much as four deaths in a single night.

- Wolf eats hunter
- Hunter shoots witch
- Witch poisons wolf
- Civilian lover of wolf dies of love sickness

All the actions are simultaniously. And winning is declared in the morning and right after lynch.

By the way, during the day a complete kill can happen too:

- Wolf and civilian lover vote for last player who happens to be the hunter.
- Hunter shoots wolf
- Civilian lover dies of life sickness.